# Website working perfectly with IE8 but not working when using the compatibility view

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-8

I've created a website ([main page](http://www.mutuelle-de-sante.eu)) that works perfectly on IE8 but not when I'm using the compatibilty view to emulate IE7 (the design of the page is messy).

Compatibility View Screenshot:

[image: Compatibility View Screenshot]

(Cropped form elements in "Votre situation familiale" section, tabs floating at top of page, mis-aligned "Demande de devis" button)

I really have no idea of how to correct this and I'm wondering if you guys have already met a similar situation and how you solved it.

Comment: Do you want to force IE8 to render in standards compat mode, or are you actually concerned about what it looks like in IE7?

Comment: @robertc I'm concerned about what it looks like in IE7 (design and form can be sent with all fields empty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a read through a list of [common IE CSS bugs](http://css-tricks.com/482-ie-css-bugs-thatll-get-you-every-time/), learn about [having layout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) and consider using [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to feed a different stylesheet to older versions of IE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it only concerns the design part and the part regarding the form being sent when it shouldn't is not covered.

Comment: @Bruno What part about the form being sent when it shouldn't?  I don't see anything about that in your question.

Comment: "the page contains a form that can be sent even with all the fields empty" (in IE7).

Comment: So you're saying it shouldn't be sent if all the fields are empty?  Sorry, that wasn't clear from your phrasing.  That sounds like a JavaScript issue, if you want two questions answered you're better off *asking* two questions.

Comment: You're right, my post is not clear enough. I'm going to update it. (Actually I use Mootools to check the form).

Comment: I would suggest asking a separate question about the form submission issue, it's a different problem and you're more like to get a response with a question title like 'Mootools form validation fails in IE8 compatibility view'